# On call of attribute_foo=(bar), call custom code, to change bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, attributes, decorator

For some reason, a simple [piece of decorator-code](https://github.com/radar/spree_localize/blob/master/app/models/spree/variant_decorator.rb#L1) fails on my production machine, but runs fine on development[1].

I dumbed it down, and found that the following is the simplest failing piece:

```
Spree::Variant.class_eval do
  def price=(value)
    self.price = normalize_number(value)
  end
end
```

Failing with `SystemStackError (stack level too deep):`

Debugging shows me that, indeed, the function keeps being called. self.price= calls price=.

What is a usual Rails/Ruby pattern to tackle this? What I want is:

When `attribute_foo=(bar)` gets called, delegate it to my custom code, where I can run the passed `bar` trough a small piece of custom code. Then assign that altered `bar` to attribute_foo.

[1]:
The only difference is the Ruby patch version and the fact that the production machine has 64-bit version, versus 32bit-version on dev: `ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [x86_64-linux]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solition was simple: just use [`write_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Write/write_attribute).

Spree::Variant.class_eval do
  def price=(value)
    write_attribute(:price, bar(value))
  end
end